# How send Direct Cursor Position Addressing in Jave Telnet Client?

Tags: java, telnet

I'm using apache.commons.net jar for my telnet client in java. I have tried `ESC[{ROW};{COLUMN}H` and `ESC[{ROW};{COLUMN}f` for direct cursor addressing but it was not working, is there any other way to do this, I'm missing something here??
Note : I'm testing with [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/examples/telnet/TelnetClientExample.java) example

Answer (score 0):

In java, you can use the literal character `27`. So, it would look like this (potentially - at least this is the best way I can think of):

```
class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print((char)27 + "c"); // clear the screen
        System.out.print((char)27 + "[H at top");
        System.out.flush(); // I would call this just to be safe (esp. if in a loop)
        System.out.print((char)27 + "[3;4H row 3; col 4");
        System.out.flush(); // I would call this just to be safe (esp. if in a loop)
        System.out.println(); // just so that the shell prompt is on the next line
    }
}
```

Basically, `(char)27` gets converted to the escape character (27, obviously), but there is another way to do this. If you are in Unix and can run `vi` or `vim` (or `emacs`, or `ed` :D, or really any editor in the terminal, I guess), you can edit the file and in `insert` mode, you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>. This will show up as `^[` but is **one** character, the *escape character 27*. This essentially forces java to interpret this as one character, and thus it works the same as `(char)27`.

This is particularly useful for shells (such as `sh`) that don't interpret multiple byte characters (? I guess). In `sh`, you can use this same procedure to force ansi escape sequences (by doing `printf "`<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>`[3;4H bla";` - *this shows up as `printf "^[[3;4 bla";`*, for example because `printf "\e[3;4 bla";` or `printf "\033[3;4 bla";` or `printf "\x1b[3;4 bla";` just won't work in `sh` because `\` is a character and then one or more characters follow).

Comment: somewhat unimportant note: the `rc` shell (AT&T Plan 9 shell) won't even interpret `ctrl`+`v`, `ctrl`+`[` `^[`.